# Pass an element from a structs array and concatenate a string in C

Tags: arrays, c, struct, casting, void-pointers

I have a structs array which contains structs that have the following definition:

```
typedef struct
{
    void *data;
    void (*print)(void *);
    status_ty (*add)(void *, int);
    void (*free_element)(void *);
} element_ty;
```

Each element can be either an "int" element, a "float" element or a "string" element.

I want to be able to `add` `int` values to each element.

For example:

`add (3, array, size_of_array);`

will loop through the array and the value of `3` will be added to each one of the elements.

`Add` is always adding an int value, For int and float elements this is normal addition, and for a string it should do concatenation.

**For example:**

- if the array contains the following elements: 4.2, 6, "welcome" - then if 3 is added to each element, the result would be: 7.2, 9, "welcome3"

My questions are:

- How should I pass the element itself to the `add` function when `add` gets a `void *` and I'm passing a pointer type of `element_ty` (the struct), which will point to this specific element in the array?
  **See my written code below, let me know if there are any mistakes there**

**This is my pseudo code for the `AddToStr` function:**

- Receive the `int` value that should be added
- Cast the existing `string` that is located in `element -> data` to `string` (?) to be able to concatenate it later? The current `data` is stored as type of `void *`.
- `malloc` the string to be able to receive the `int` value?
- cast it again to `void *` and store it in `element -> data`?
- `free()` the `malloc`?

I'm so confused.

This is what I have wrote so far:

```
    void FreeStrElement(void *(element_ty *element))
{

    free(element -> data);  

}


/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    void AddToInt(void *(element_ty *element), int IncrementValue)
{

    int data = (int) element -> data;
    int sum = data + IncrementValue;
    element -> data = (void *) sum; 

}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void AddToFlt(void *(element_ty *element), int IncrementValue)
{

    float data = (float *) element -> data;
    float sum = data + IncrementValue;
    element -> data = (void *) *(float *)&sum;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void AddToStr(void *(element_ty *element), int IncrementValue)
{

    ??

}


/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void PrintStr(void *num)
{

    printf("String in the element: %s\n", (char **) &num);  

}


/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

status_ty InitStr(const char *value, element_ty *element)
{
    element -> data = (void *)value;
    element -> print = PrintStr;
    element -> add = AddtoStr;
    element -> free_element = FreeStrElement;
    
}
```

Comment: Using C++ as an example, the first parameter to each of the functions (`print`, `add`, `free_element`) should be a pointer to the struct, e.g. `(*add)(element_ty *this, int x)`. Then you can get the `data` from the struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions that are assigned to each element need to take an `element*` as input, as they need to be able to modify the `data` member as needed.  This is especially important for "string" elements, since you need to be able to reallocate the string memory when adding more characters, which means assigning a new `char*` pointer to the `data`.

You can pass in the `element*` pointers as `void*` parameters (which you said is required), but you will have to type-cast the `void*` back to `element*` *inside* the function bodies.

Try something like this:

```c
typedef struct
{
    void *data;
    void (*print)(void *);
    status_ty (*add)(void *, int);
    void (*free_element)(void *);
} element_ty;

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void FreeStrElement(void *element)
{
    element_ty *p_element = (element_ty *) element;
    free(p_element->data);
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

status_ty AddToInt(void *element, int IncrementValue)
{
    element_ty *p_element = (element_ty *) element;
    int *p_value = (int*) &(p_element->data);
    *p_value += IncrementValue;
    return ...;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

status_ty AddToFlt(void *element, int IncrementValue)
{
    element_ty *p_element = (element_ty *) element;
    float *p_value = (float*) &(p_element->data);
    *p_value += IncrementValue;
    return ...;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

status_ty AddToStr(void *element, int IncrementValue)
{
    element_ty *p_element = (element_ty *) element;
    char *p_str = (char*) p_element->data;

    char *new_str = realloc(p_str, strlen(p_str) + 13);
    if (!new_str) return ...;

    sprintf(new_str, "%s%d", p_str, IncrementValue);

    p_element->data = new_str;

    return ...;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void PrintInt(void *element)
{
    element_ty *p_element = (element_ty *) element;
    int *p_value = (int*) &(p_element->data);
    printf("Integer in the element: %d\n", *p_value);
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void PrintFlt(void *element)
{
    element_ty *p_element = (element_ty *) element;
    float *p_value = (float*) &(p_element->data);
    printf("Float in the element: %f\n", *p_value);
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void PrintStr(void *element)
{
    element_ty *p_element = (element_ty *) element;
    char *p_str = (char*) p_element->data;
    printf("String in the element: %s\n", p_str);
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

status_ty InitInt(int value, element_ty *element)
{
    int *p_value = (int*) &(element->data);
    *p_value = value;
    element->print = &PrintInt;
    element->add = &AddToInt;
    element->free_element = NULL;

    return ...;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

status_ty InitFlt(float value, element_ty *element)
{
    float *p_value = (float*) &(element->data);
    *p_value = value;
    element->print = &PrintFlt;
    element->add = &AddToFlt;
    element->free_element = NULL;

    return ...;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

status_ty InitStr(const char *value, element_ty *element)
{
    element->data = strdup(value);
    element->print = &PrintStr;
    element->add = &AddToStr;
    element->free_element = &FreeStrElement;

    return ...;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Then you can do things like this:

```c
void add (int value, element_ty *elements, int n) {
    for(int i = 0 i < n; ++i) {
        element_ty *elem = &elements[i];
        elem->add(elem, value);
    }
}

void print (element_ty *elements, int n) {
    for(int i = 0 i < n; ++i) {
        element_ty *elem = &elements[i];
        elem->print(elem);
    }
}

void free_elements (element_ty *elements, int n) {
    for(int i = 0 i < n; ++i) {
        element_ty *elem = &elements[i];
        if (elem->free_element) elem->free_element(elem);
    }
}
```

That being said, this approach assumes `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(float)` are <= `sizeof(void*)`, which is *usually* the case, but not guaranteed.

This approach also violates Strict Aliasing rules. You can use `memcpy()` to avoid that, but using a `union` instead would be easier and cleaner (it also avoids the `sizeof` issue, too), eg:

```c
typedef struct
{
    union {
        int i;
        float f;
        char *s;
    } data;
    void (*print)(void *);
    status_ty (*add)(void *, int);
    void (*free_element)(void *);
} element_ty;

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void FreeStrElement(void *element)
{
    element_ty *p_element = (element_ty *) element;
    free(p_element->data.s);
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

status_ty AddToInt(void *element, int IncrementValue)
{
    element_ty *p_element = (element_ty *) element;
    p_element->data.i += IncrementValue;
    return ...;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

status_ty AddToFlt(void *element, int IncrementValue)
{
    element_ty *p_element = (element_ty *) element;
    p_element->data.f += IncrementValue;
    return ...;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

status_ty AddToStr(void *element, int IncrementValue)
{
    element_ty *p_element = (element_ty *) element;
    char *p_str = p_element->data.s;

    char *new_str = realloc(p_str, strlen(p_str) + 13);
    if (!new_str) return ...;

    sprintf(new_str, "%s%d", p_str, IncrementValue);

    p_element->data.s = new_str;

    return ...;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void PrintInt(void *element)
{
    element_ty *p_element = (element_ty *) element;
    printf("Integer in the element: %d\n", p_element->data.i);
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void PrintFlt(void *element)
{
    element_ty *p_element = (element_ty *) element;
    printf("Float in the element: %f\n", p_element->data.f);
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void PrintStr(void *element)
{
    element_ty *p_element = (element_ty *) element;
    printf("String in the element: %s\n", p_element->data.s);
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

status_ty InitInt(int value, element_ty *element)
{
    element->data.i = value;
    element->print = &PrintInt;
    element->add = &AddToInt;
    element->free_element = NULL;

    return ...;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

status_ty InitFlt(float value, element_ty *element)
{
    element->data.f = value;
    element->print = &PrintFlt;
    element->add = &AddToFlt;
    element->free_element = NULL;

    return ...;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

status_ty InitStr(const char *value, element_ty *element)
{
    element->data.s = strdup(value);
    element->print = &PrintStr;
    element->add = &AddToStr;
    element->free_element = &FreeStrElement;

    return ...;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your elaborated answer, I appreciate it! But.. the definition of the structure and the function pointers that inside of it are given to me and cannot be changed. Therefore they have to take void * as it says and not element *

Comment: In that case, you are declaring the functions incorrectly, and some of your type-casts are wrong. I have updated my answer to show the correct way to handle this.

Comment: Why do I need to `malloc` in the `InitInt` and `InitFlt` functions? `int` types do not require any memory allocation, correct me if i'm wrong? 

Second question is about my mistakes:
1. Why can't I use the code as I have wrote it?
` int data = (int) element -> data;`

2. Why can't I receive the element as `void *` as I wrote:
`void AddToInt(void *(element_ty *element), int IncrementValue)`?

Why `void *(element_ty *element)` is wrong?

Comment: @NoobCoder 1) the `malloc` is not strictly needed, that is why I wrote the second example that uses a `union`, which is safer and cleaner than using type-casts to access different types of `data`. Also, your `int` handling was fine, but your `float` handling was completely broken. 2) because that syntax is completely wrong. You can't pass in a parameter as two different types at the same time.

Comment: @NoobCoder I have updated my 1st example to remove the `malloc()`s for non-string elements.

Comment: Thanks, everythings seems to work. I actually wrote it in a different way: `element -> data = (void *) (long) value;` in the `InitInt` function for example. and `printf("Integer in the element: %d\n", (int)(p_element->data));` in the `PrintInt` function. What do  you think about it? It seems to work as well.

Comment: @NoobCoder an `int` can be directly casted to/from `void*` like that, but a `float` cannot. For that reason alone, I chose a different approach that works for both types more consistently.

Comment: Why do we need to add `13` when we `realloc`?
`char *new_data = realloc(data, strlen(data) + 13);`

Comment: @NoobCoder a 32bit `int` can have a max of 10 digits, so that needs room for up to 10 chars when converted to a string (11 for the `-` sign if the `int` is negative). And a C string needs a null terminator. I included a byte or two extra, for good measure.

Comment: Aren't we "lose" memory by assigining "too much" for nothing? We assign memory for max digits, which will cause to a lot of memory to be "spent" for nothing, don't you think? Can't we `malloc `or `realloc` by the `sizeof` the `IncrementValue`? Is it possible to avoid assigning `13` ?

Comment: @NoobCoder "*Aren't we "lose" memory by assigning "too much"?*" - it would take A LOT of allocated `element_ty` instances, like say millions, for those extra bytes to even really make a noticeable dent in the computer's available memory. And in any case, the allocated memory is likely coming from a larger pool to begin with, so it would have been allocated anyway.

Comment: @NoobCoder "*Can't we `malloc` or `realloc` by the `sizeof` the `IncrementValue`?*" - not by `sizeof`, which is a compile-time constant. An `int` has a fixed byte size regardless of its value at runtime. But as a string, `"1"` needs less memory than `"2147483647"`. If you are worried about it, then you need to calculate the *exact* amount of memory to allocate, such as with `vsnprintf()`, eg: `int len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, "%s%d", p_str, IncrementValue) + 1; char *new_str = realloc(p_str, len); ... sprintf(new_str, "%s%d", p_str, IncrementValue);`

Comment: Thank you for all your help!


Why did you created `element_ty *p_element`? We could handle it without creating it, and just accessing the original element. What `p_` stands for in the beginning of the name?

Comment: @NoobCoder "*Why did you created `element_ty *p_element`?*" - to make the code easier to read and maintain, and to show its intent. "*We could handle it without creating it*" - sure. Just like we can technically write assembly code instead of using higher level C code. You want to be able to come back to the code months/years later and still be able to understand it. "*What `p_` stands for in the beginning of the name?*" - that it is a pointer